# Node.js at command promt is not completing calculations, how do I discover why?

Tags: node.js, linux, volume, calculation

**Using Visual Studio as my editor, code is an example from Linux Professional Institute, so should be correct:**

```
const sphereVol = (radius) => {
    return 4/3 * Math.PI * radius
}

console.log('A sphere with radius 3 has a ${sphereVol(3)} volume.');
console.log('A sphere with radius 6 has a ${sphereVol(6)} volume.');
```

**When I attempt to run in Node.js environment through command prompt instead of completing the calculation and inserting it in the string for output, it outputs: **

```
C:\Users\court\node-examples-LPI>node ./volumeCalculator.js
A sphere with a radius 3 has a ${sphereVol(3)} volume.
A sphere with radius 6 has a ${sphereVol(6)} volume.
```

Thank you!

I am a beginner and I tried it exactly as stated above based on the Linux Professional Institute example. I have tried to see if there was some sort of module I was missing, but the node installed is the latest stable version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to you logic you want to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
Actually for pass to console.log you've to use **backtick(`)** instead of **single quotes(')**

```
console.log(`A sphere with radius 3 has a ${sphereVol(3)} volume.`);
console.log(`A sphere with radius 6 has a ${sphereVol(6)} volume.`);
```

OR

Anothe solution is string concatenation (old fashioned):

```
console.log('A sphere with radius 3 has a '+ sphereVol(3)+ ' volume.');
console.log('A sphere with radius 6 has a '+ sphereVol(6)+ ' volume.');
```